# What is CALLBACK Data type in windows.h?

Tags: windows, callback

why data type in windows.h have CALLBACK ?

how to use it ?

what is the difference between other data type ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is right there in the page you linked to:

> CALLBACK, WINAPI, and APIENTRY are all used to define functions with
>   the __stdcall calling convention. Most functions in the Windows API
>   are declared using WINAPI. You may wish to use CALLBACK for the
>   callback functions that you implement to help identify the function as
>   a callback function.

On 32-bit Windows x86 machines there are multiple [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) but the two most common are stdcall and cdecl. Most functions in the Windows API are stdcall and functions in the C standard library are cdecl.

Most public functions in the Windows SDK use the WINAPI define while callback functions that you or a library create will usually use the CALLBACK define. They both end up declaring that the function is using the stdcall calling convention and the generated code is the same. The CALLBACK define is used just as a reminder to you, the programmer, that this particular function is a callback function.